# Yield multiple iterators and then flatten not working as expected

Tags: scala

As below code yields 50 Iterator[String] . Should flattening this collection return 50 instead of 1 ?

```
  val v1: Iterator[String] = List("1").toIterator

  val l: Iterator[String] = (for (a <- 1 to 50) yield v1).flatten.toIterator

  println(l.size)
```

It appears the iteration is being overwritten each time with loop ?

Answer (score 0):

No, as iterator is mutable, so after first step of traversion (as part of flattening) it becomes empty. In other words, this first step produces side-effect shared between all **remaining** elements as they all are referencing same iterator. So, during reconciliation (see below), first element becomes memorized as `Vector(1)` and others are becoming empty vectors. Your `(for (a <- 1 to 50) yield v1).flatten` actually returns `Vector(1)`, so step with converting it to iterator again is redundant as previous iterator was already materialized. Even without `flatten`, just conversion `toVector` shows that:

```
scala> val v1: Iterator[String] = List("1").toIterator
v1: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

scala> val v = (for (a <- 1 to 50) yield v1).toVector
v: Vector[Iterator[String]] = Vector(non-empty iterator, non-empty iterator, non-empty iterator, ...

scala> v.head.toVector
res16: Vector[String] = Vector(1)

scala> v.head.toVector
res20: Vector[String] = Vector()

scala> v.tail.head.toVector
res17: Vector[String] = Vector()
```

`flatten` has to convert `Iterator` to `Vector` because it needs to make `Vector[Vector[T]]` from `Vector[Iterator[T]]` to reconcile monadic layers prior to their consolidation (flattening).

Talking about size of iterator:

```
scala> val v1: Iterator[String] = List("1").toIterator
v1: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

scala> v1.size
res18: Int = 1

scala> v1.size
res19: Int = 0
```

As a conclusion, size of resulting `Vector(1).toIterator` is obviously `1` (but only first time).

Generally speaking, the "paradox" is happend only because iterator is mutable, so it's not purely functional (mathematical) usage of Scala - which means that results can be different from normal logical expectations (but still correct). Imperative meets functional O_o.

P.S. You can partially avoid problems caused by side-effects with `Stream`s instead of iterators. They are still lazy but memorize elements during creation:

```
scala> val v1: Stream[String] = List("1").toStream
v1: Stream[String] = Stream(1, ?)

scala> val l: Stream[String] = (for (a <- 1 to 50) yield v1).flatten.toStream
l: Stream[String] = Stream(1, ?)

scala> l.size
res21: Int = 50
```

A `Stream`-based code may never terminate (same as iterator-based), which is still a problem for methematical-like programming. And, in contrast to iterators, streams can cause `OutOfMemory` because of memorizing. Also, stream is always calculating its head. Besides all this, they're pretty fine.